# Маппинг колонки значений в колонку с ключами по набору соответствующих пар ключ - значение

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть задача проставить автоматически  в колонку с number нужные числа напротив колонки с name. выделил серым на скрине.

слева таблица соотвествий.

т.е. нужно такую формулу чтобы получилось как на скрине 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно формулой описать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ПРОСМОТРХ() в  Office 365 или ВПР() в более ранних версиях

Comment: =ВПР(E2;$A$2:$B$5;2;)